# How I can add more hidden layers on the nftool code that I exported from the nnstart GUI?

Tags: matlab, command-line, neural-network, nntool

Since I don't know much about how to implement a network using command line, I tried using the GUI from NNSTART and exported the code so I could try to figure out how to make the changes I need. the problems is that I don't how to add more layers/neurons, even more ephocs.

Here is the code I got from my first attempt:

```
% Solve an Input-Output Fitting problem with a Neural Network
% Script generated by Neural Fitting app
% Created 13-Sep-2017 20:47:36
%
% This script assumes these variables are defined:
%
%   Input_train - input data.
%   Target_train - target data.

x = Input_train;
t = Target_train;

% Choose a Training Function
% For a list of all training functions type: help nntrain
% 'trainlm' is usually fastest.
% 'trainbr' takes longer but may be better for challenging problems.
% 'trainscg' uses less memory. Suitable in low memory situations. 
trainFcn = 'trainlm';  % Levenberg-Marquardt backpropagation.

% Create a Fitting Network
hiddenLayerSize = 23;
net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize,trainFcn);

% Choose Input and Output Pre/Post-Processing Functions
% For a list of all processing functions type: help nnprocess
net.input.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};
net.output.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};

% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
% For a list of all data division functions type: help nndivide
net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';  % Divide data randomly
net.divideMode = 'sample';  % Divide up every sample
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 80/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 10/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 10/100;

% Choose a Performance Function
% For a list of all performance functions type: help nnperformance
net.performFcn = 'mse';  % Mean Squared Error

% Choose Plot Functions
% For a list of all plot functions type: help nnplot
net.plotFcns = {'plotperform','plottrainstate','ploterrhist', ...
'plotregression', 'plotfit'};

% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,x,t);
% Test the Network
y = net(x);
e = gsubtract(t,y);
performance = perform(net,t,y)

% Recalculate Training, Validation and Test Performance
trainTargets = t .* tr.trainMask{1};
valTargets = t .* tr.valMask{1};
testTargets = t .* tr.testMask{1};
trainPerformance = perform(net,trainTargets,y)
valPerformance = perform(net,valTargets,y)
testPerformance = perform(net,testTargets,y)

% View the Network
view(net)

% Plots
% Uncomment these lines to enable various plots.
%figure, plotperform(tr)
%figure, plottrainstate(tr)
%figure, ploterrhist(e)
%figure, plotregression(t,y)
%figure, plotfit(net,x,t)
```

end